# Error: Method not found: 'Observable.combineLatest2'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, rxdart

Compiler message:
lib/app/home/entries/entries_bloc.dart:17:62: Error: Method not found: 'Observable.combineLatest2'.
  Stream> get _allEntriesStream => Observable.combineLatest2(
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
Stream<List<EntryJob>> get _allEntriesStream => Observable.combineLatest2(
   database.entriesStream(),
   database.jobsStream(),
   _entriesJobsCombiner,
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
Observable.combineLatest2(
   database.entriesStream(),
   database.jobsStream(),
   _entriesJobsCombiner,
 );
```

into this:

```
Rx.combineLatest2(
   database.entriesStream(),
   database.jobsStream(),
   _entriesJobsCombiner,
 );
```

The `Rx` utility class contains the method `combineLatest2`

https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx-class.html